# Would threading help me process images faster?

Tags: java, multithreading, image-processing, color-detection

I am using Java to create a color detection algorithm.

Here is how it works:

1. A screen capture is taken of a portion of the screen around the cursor
2. Every pixel in that capture is checked to see if it is within a range of colors or not
3. The average of valid pixels is calculated
4. The cursor is moved to that average

I am hoping to get it to work at 50 - 100 times per second. For the most part the time taken to complete the process does take under 20 ms. However, sometimes it goes over 20 ms, and it takes even longer for bigger screen captures. So, I was thinking of using threads to help solve my problem. However, I have heard that threads split the CPUs processing power. So, I was wondering if using multiple threads to process these captures would help my program run faster.

Comment: This should really be done on the graphics card. This might help you: https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/programming-the-gpu-in-java

Comment: @ControlAltDel I only want to process images, not render them

Comment: Would using multiple threads help your program run faster? I would say, *most likely, yes*. Given that most modern CPUs have multiple cores, you should be able to run multiple tasks in parallell without sacrificing the speed of a single task. However, keep in mind that multithreading also comes with a cost whenever the threads need to share data. I would also not be surprised if the actual screen capture would need to run on a designated UI thread. So the gain may not be worth the extra complexity... As usual, YMMV...

Comment: It depends why it **occasionally** takes longer than 20ms.  If the reason is GC pauses, then multi-threading is not likely to help.